# Exclude for a specific product the field validation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce website and every product have IMEI field. I need only for a specific product to remove the field validation (to not check IMEI field). I tried many ways I can't get it work.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

And the code:

```
function custom_output_engraving_field() {
    $product;
    ?>
    <div class="imei-engraving-field">
        <label for="imei-values" name="suwp-imei-values-label">IMEI: <br> (Enter 15 digits), dial *#06# to display </label>
         <input type="text" id="imei-engraving" name="imei-engraving" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter engraving text', 'myimei' ); ?>" maxlength="15">
         <label for="imeinote-values" name="suwp-imeinote-values-label">IMEI Note: </label>
         <textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="imeinote-engraving" name="imeinote-engraving" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter engraving text', 'myimeinote' ); ?>"> </textarea>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_output_engraving_field', 15 );

function suwpimei_custom_fields_validation($true, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    $imei_values = trim($_REQUEST['imei-engraving']);

    $imei = trim($imei_values);
    $chk_dup_imei[] = $imei;
    $serial_length = 15;
    $actual_length = (int)strlen($imei);
    $flag_continue_imei = TRUE;
    $flag_msg_imei = array();

    if ( empty( $imei_values ) ) {
        // empty submission
        $flag_continue_imei = FALSE;
        $flag_msg_imei = 'Please enter at least one IMEI.<br />';

    } else {
        if ( $actual_length != $serial_length && suwpimei_is_digits($imei) == 1 ) {

            $flag_continue_imei = FALSE;
            $flag_msg_imei = $imei . ' should be ' . $serial_length . ' characters, not '. $actual_length . '. This is not a valid IMEI entry.<br />';

        }

        if ( suwpimei_is_digits($imei) != 1 ) {

            $flag_continue_imei = FALSE;
            $flag_msg_imei = $imei . ' is invalid. IMEI should be digits only: no letters, punctuation, or spaces.<br />';

        }

        if ( $actual_length == $serial_length && suwpimei_is_digits($imei) == 1 ) {

            // only do the suwp_check_imei when imei is 15 digits
            if ($serial_length == 15) {

                if (suwpimei_check_imei($imei) == 0) {

                    $flag_continue_imei = FALSE;
                    $flag_msg_imei = $imei . ' is not a valid IMEI entry.<br />';

                }
            }
        }
    }

    $flag_msg_string = '';
    $flag_msg_string = $flag_msg_imei;

    if ( !$flag_continue_imei ) {
        wc_add_notice( $flag_msg_string, 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    if( ! empty ( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) ) {
        //WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        wc_add_notice( 'Only allowed 1 item in cart, please remove previous item.', 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'suwpimei_custom_fields_validation', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Just compare the $product_id passed in suwpimei_custom_fields_validation() against the that specific product. If it is same, don't validate the field.

Comment: thank your fast reply. My product id 873 I tried compare  may be I can't get the id something else can you please edit my code 

advance thanks

Comment: Which field should not be validated, IMEI or IMEI Note?

Comment: both field IMEI and IMEI Note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the $product_id against the product which you don't want to validate.

```
function suwpimei_custom_fields_validation( $true, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    // Compare against the product which you don't want to validate.
    // If it matches, just bail out, return whatever is passed in $true.
    if ( $product_id == 873 ) {
        return $true;
    }

    $imei_values        = trim( $_REQUEST['imei-engraving'] );
    $imei               = trim( $imei_values );
    $chk_dup_imei[]     = $imei;
    $serial_length      = 15;
    $actual_length      = intval( strlen( $imei ) );
    $flag_continue_imei = true;
    $flag_msg_imei      = array();

    if ( empty( $imei_values ) ) {
        // empty submission.
        $flag_continue_imei = false;
        $flag_msg_imei = 'Please enter at least one IMEI.<br />';
    } else {

        if ( $actual_length != $serial_length && suwpimei_is_digits( $imei ) == 1 ) {
            $flag_continue_imei = false;
            $flag_msg_imei = $imei . ' should be ' . $serial_length . ' characters, not ' . $actual_length . '. This is not a valid IMEI entry.<br />';
        }

        if ( suwpimei_is_digits( $imei ) != 1 ) {

            $flag_continue_imei = false;
            $flag_msg_imei = $imei . ' is invalid. IMEI should be digits only: no letters, punctuation, or spaces.<br />';

        }

        if ( $actual_length == $serial_length && suwpimei_is_digits( $imei ) == 1 ) {

            // only do the suwp_check_imei when imei is 15 digits
            if ($serial_length == 15) {

                if (suwpimei_check_imei($imei) == 0) {

                    $flag_continue_imei = FALSE;
                    $flag_msg_imei = $imei . ' is not a valid IMEI entry.<br />';

                }
            }

        }

    }

    $flag_msg_string = '';
    $flag_msg_string = $flag_msg_imei;

    if ( ! $flag_continue_imei ) {
        wc_add_notice( $flag_msg_string, 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    if( ! empty ( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) ) {
        //WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        wc_add_notice( 'Only allowed 1 item in cart, please remove previous item.', 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'suwpimei_custom_fields_validation', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: @sifat Glad to help. :)